# Race condition with stream listen

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have an async function like below. However content is being returned null well before the stream listening is done.

I started playing out with Future.delayed, but thought better of it and wanted to ask if there is a better approach to ensure this is async?

```
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;

static Future<String> getContentsFromFile() async {
String content;

ga.Media mediaResponse = await drive.files.get(fileId);

mediaResponse.stream.listen((data) {
    print("DataReceived: "+data);
    content = data
  }, onDone: () async {
    print("Task Done");
  }, onError: (error) {
    print("Some Error");
  });
return content;
}
```

Im calling the function like so..

```
String content = await getContentsFromFile();
```

Comment: What is the stream you are listening to?

Comment: A google drive file ( Media ), it should read media.stream.listen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Made the example more complete, with handling of errors and partial content.

You can use [Completer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/Completer-class.html) for this sort of control flow:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;

static Future<String> getContentsFromFile() async {
  Completer<String> completer = Completer();
  String content = "";

  ga.Media mediaResponse = await drive.files.get(fileId);

  mediaResponse.stream.listen((data) {
    print("DataReceived: "+data);
    content += data;
  }, onDone: () async {
    print("Task Done");
    completer.complete(content);
  }, onError: (error) {
    print("Some Error");
    completer.completeError(error);
  });

  return completer.future;
}
```